# Async function in dot net mvc5 controller creating deadlock

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, payment-gateway

I am using this library for Bangladeshi payment gateway.https://github.com/Rahim373/Arts.SslCommerze
.But code in a controller awaiting iis for infinite time. I checked in fiddler if the response is reaching from server to my machine properly. and it was reaching. But the async function is not executing.
My code is:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
        string customerName = "Fahim Abrar";
        string customerEmail = "fahim@gmail.com";
        string customerPhone = "+8801845";
        string transactionId = "45c2ffc4d";
        string successUrl = "http://abrar.com";
        string failUrl = "http://fahimabrar.com";
        string cancelUrl = "cancelUrl";
        decimal amount = 50;

        Customer customer = new Customer(customerName, customerEmail, 
        customerPhone);

        EmiTransaction emiTransaction = new 
        EmiTransaction(isEmiEnabled: false);

        Trasnaction trasnaction = new Trasnaction(amount, 
        transactionId, successUrl, failUrl,
            cancelUrl, emiTransaction, customer);

  SslRequest.GetSessionAsync(trasnaction).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        var session = SslRequest.GetSessionAsync(trasnaction).Result;
        string s = session.FailedReason;

        ViewBag.Message = s;
        //"Your application description page.";

        return View();
}
```

Here var session = SslRequest.GetSessionAsync(trasnaction).Result;
this line is causing a deadlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Result` can cause deadlocks.

Make your method `async` and use `await` e.g.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> About()
{
    string customerName = "Fahim Abrar";
    string customerEmail = "fahimabrar13@gmail.com";
    string customerPhone = "+8801853912845";
    string transactionId = "45c2ffc4d";
    string successUrl = "http://fahimabrar.com";
    string failUrl = "http://fahimabrar.com";
    string cancelUrl = "cancelUrl";
    decimal amount = 50;

    Customer customer = new Customer(customerName, customerEmail, 
    customerPhone);

    EmiTransaction emiTransaction = new 
    EmiTransaction(isEmiEnabled: false);

    Trasnaction trasnaction = new Trasnaction(amount, 
    transactionId, successUrl, failUrl,
        cancelUrl, emiTransaction, customer);

    var session = await SslRequest.GetSessionAsync(trasnaction);
    string s = session.FailedReason;

    ViewBag.Message = s;
    //"Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
```

See: [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: that is giving the error "
**Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.**

Comment: Where, @FahimAbrar?

Comment: In visual studio build

Comment: You want to `await` that line (and make the method `async Task<...>`); don't use `.Result`